# Reticulate vs Python

Tags: python, r

I have gotten very used to coding in R and especially in RStudio. I like that interface. Nonetheless, I have some work that I ought to do in Python. I know that I can run Python code in RStudio if I use the "reticulate" package, and I've written some code that has switched between the two. As far as I can tell, anything I could run in Python from the command line or in Jupyter could be done in RStudio with reticulate.

Should I expect to have longer run times using Python commands in R, than I would if I ran Python regularly (whatever "regularly" means)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually tested this recently on a random forest fitting using two approaches:

1. Using Jupyter notebooks to fit my model via `python` with data that had been tidied in the same notebook also using `python`.

vs:

2. Using `reticulate` in a rstudio notebook to fit the same model in `python` but using a converted dataset I had tidied in `r` in the same notebook.

I made the following observations:

1. Native `python` **is faster**, in my benchmark it fitted the model ~1 min faster (9 vs 10 mins) on my 16GB Ram laptop.
2. Additionally you lose some time converting objects between the two languages, especially if we talk about bigger datasets.

**Conclusion**

In most cases doing `r` stuff first, saving objects to CSV and then opening jupyter or `python` command lines to finish a job is not necessary thanks to `reticulate`.

If you do a repeated or time-critical job try to use python natively but otherwise `reticulate` is fine especially, if like me you save a lot of time doing prep work in `r`.

Comment: Great Work!  This knowledge is a time saver.  Thank you.